# Kafka connect size based rollover with time based rollover on individual partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using Kafka connect to sink files to HDFS , Kafka connect has TopicPartitionWriter which does rollover on time to all partitions  and there is no size based rollover .

I want to do size based and time based rollover but for each partitions because as data passing though each partition is not uniform, also similar size files.

2 questions:
1. If I try to do this by changing a lot of code in Kafka connect that will loose original design ?
2. Is there any thing done for my use case ?

Answer (score 0):

> TopicPartitionWriter which does rollover on time to all partitions and there is no size based rollover

`flush.size` is still (and always) used.

> If I try to do this by changing a lot of code in Kafka connect that will loose original design

No? As long as data goes from Kafka to some external system, that's the only contract that Connect Sink API provides

> Is there any thing done for my use case ?

Scan the issues and PRs of the Github repo

Comment: flush.size controls # of records but if not all messages are of same bytes then 
I will end up in different size files in hfs

Comment: Correct. And there is no way around that, AFAIK. As long as files are larger than the HDFS block size, does that matter?

Comment: I have used sequence file in append mode and doing flush based on temp file size 
https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs/compare/5.5.x...vipinkumar7:5.5.x?expand=1